# How to test a machine learning model?

Tags: testing, machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I want to develop a framework(for QA testing purpose) that validates a machine learning model. I had a lot of discussions with my peers and read articles from the google.

Most of the discussions or articles are telling machine learning model will evolve with the test data that we provide. correct me if I'm wrong.

What is the possibility of developing a framework that validates the machine learning model will give accurate results?

Few ways to test the model from the articles I read: Split and Multi-split technique, Metamorphic testing

Please also suggest any other approaches

Answer (score 2):

QA testing of ML-based software requires additional, and rather unconventional, tests because oftentimes their outputs for a given set of inputs are not defined, deterministic, or known a priori and they produce approximations rather than exact results.

QA may be designed to test against:

1. naive but predictable benchmark methods: the [average method](https://otexts.org/fpp2/simple-methods.html) in forecasting, the class-frequency-based classifier in classification, etc.
2. [sanity checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check) (the outputs being feasible/rational): e.g., is the predicted age positive?
3. preset objective acceptance levels: e.g., is its [AUCROC](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132777/what-does-auc-stand-for-and-what-is-it) > 0.5?
4. extreme/boundary cases: e.g., thunderstorm conditions for a weather forecast model.
5. [bias-variance tradeoff](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~smyth/courses/cs274/readings/xing_singh_CMU_bias_variance.pdf): what is its performance on in-sample and out-of-sample data? K-Fold [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) is useful here.
6. the model itself: is the [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) of its performance measure (e.g., AUCROC) from *n* runs on the same data for same/random train and test partitioning within a reasonable bound?

Some of these tests need performance measures. [Here](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs578/2003fa/performance_measures.pdf) is a comprehensive library of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the data flow is, *actually*, the one that needs to be tested here such as raw input, manipulation, test output and predictions. For example, if you have a simple linear model you actually want to test the *predictions* produced from that model instead of the *coefficients* of the model. So, maybe, the high level steps are summarized as below;

1. **Raw Input:** Does the raw input make sense? Before you start manipulating, you need to be sure the raw data values are within the expected limits. For example, if you normally see 5-10% NA rate in some data, having 95% NA rate in a new batch might be an indicator that something is wrong.
2. **Train/Predict Ready Input:** Either you train a new model or feeding new data into a already trained model for prediction, you probably want to be sure that manipulated data makes sense, too. Some ML algorithms are delicate to data anomalies. You don't want to predict a credit score around thousands just because you have some data anomalies in the input.
3. **Model Success:** By this time, you should have some idea about your model success. So, you can measure the model's performance on a new test data. You can also check train and test score if they are not significantly different (i.e. Overfitting). If you're retraining, you can compare with the previous training scores. Or, you can separate some test set and compare its score.
4. **Predictions:** Finally, you need to be sure your final output makes sense before delivering to production/clients. For example, if you're revenue forecasting for a very small shop, the daily revenue predictions can't be million dollars or some negative amounts.

Full disclosure, I wrote a small Python package for this. You can check [here](https://github.com/ddaskan/mlqa) or download as below,

```
pip install mlqa
```